# React render props to UI and map all the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, render

I am trying to render all the props to the UI, however, I use stateless function and map all the props to the HTML . I got this issue `Uncaught TypeError: props.map is not a function`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this bug. I am new to React, thanks for your help.

```
import React from 'react';

function CurrentlyRead(props) {
    
      props.map((prop) => {
        const title  = prop.title;
        const author = prop.author;
        const url    = prop.url;
        return (
        <div className="bookshelf-books">
            <ol className="book-grid">
                 <div className="book-cover" style={{
                  width: 128,
                  height: 193,
                  backgroundImage: url,
                }}>
                </div>
                <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                <select>
                    <option value="move" disabled> Move to ... </option>
                    <option value="currentReading">Currently reading</option>
                    <option value="read">Read</option>
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                    <div className="book-title">{title}</div>
                    <div className="book-authors">{author}</div>
            </ol>
        </div>  
    )}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Props is not an array. It's an object. So you should work with props like with an object. In your case I prefer using of destructuring of props. Also don't forget export your function

```
import React from 'react';

function CurrentlyRead({ title, author, url }) {
        return (
        <div className="bookshelf-books">
            <ol className="book-grid">
                 <div className="book-cover" style={{
                  width: 128,
                  height: 193,
                  backgroundImage: url,
                }}>
                </div>
                <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                <select>
                    <option value="move" disabled> Move to ... </option>
                    <option value="currentReading">Currently reading</option>
                    <option value="read">Read</option>
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                    <div className="book-title">{title}</div>
                    <div className="book-authors">{author}</div>
            </ol>
        </div>  
    )
}
```

Comment: Normally, we pass props as function argument. however, if this props has multiple title, author,  url. Can we map to get all the value here?  Your answer is only valid for single property. right ?

Comment: For example if you received an array of multiple authors, you can map it. You can read more about "Rendering Multiple Elements" by react documentation. But if you want use just one value from array I offer you use reduce